# Cannot parse JSON with Gson: cannot cast error

Tags: android, json, android-studio, kotlin, gson

I have these data classes:

```
data class GenericApiOutput<T>(
    var success: Boolean?,
    var data: T?
)

data class PricePlan(
    var id: Int,
    var price: Float,
    var name: String
)
```

And I'm trying to parse a JSON string as follows:

```
inline fun <reified MyType> requestInterpreter(request: Request, crossinline successCallback: (final_result: MyType) -> Unit, crossinline failureCallback: (errors: ApiErrors ) -> Unit ) {
    
    val test = """{"success":true, "data": {"id":1,"price_per_kw_in_cents":100,"name":"blah"} }"""
    val test2 = """{"id":1,"price_per_kw_in_cents":100,"name":"blah"}"""

    val res0 = parseOutput< GenericApiOutput<MyType> >( test)
    println(res0) // => GenericApiOutput(success=true, data={id=1.0, price_per_kw_in_cents=100.0, name=blah})

    val res = fromJson< GenericApiOutput<PricePlan> >(test)
    println(res) // => GenericApiOutput(success=true, data=PricePlan(id=1, price_per_kw_in_cents=100, name=blah))
    println(res.data) // => PricePlan(id=1, price_per_kw_in_cents=100, name=blah)

    val res2 = fromJson< GenericApiOutput<MyType> >(test)
    println(res2) // => GenericApiOutput(success=true, data={id=1.0, price_per_kw_in_cents=100.0, name=blah})
    println(res2.data) // => {id=1.0, price_per_kw_in_cents=100.0, name=blah}

    var res3 = Gson().fromJson(Gson().toJson(res.data), PricePlan::class.java)
    println(res3) // => PricePlan(id=1, price_per_kw_in_cents=100, name=blah)

    val res4 = Gson().fromJson<PricePlan>(test2, PricePlan::class.java)
    println(res4) // => PricePlan(id=1, price_per_kw_in_cents=100, name=blah)
}
```

The other two functions are:

```
inline fun <reified T> fromJson(json: String?): T {
    return Gson().fromJson<T>(json, object: TypeToken<T>(){}.type)
}

inline fun <reified MyType> parseOutput(json_response: String): MyType {
    return fromJson< MyType >(json_response)
}
```

I don't really understand what's going on. How do I get it to work?

Comment: Could you show us the raw json text you're trying to parse?

Comment: I've added a piece, it's pretty straightforward. Also it parses correctly without that TypeToken magic, but I'd rather not duplicate any code (I have like 30 different API calls I'm using)

Comment: Trying to not duplicating code is a good vertue! By editing your post you have removed your question and the error though. Could you re-add tthe question and state which error is thrown. Which lines do work, which lines do not? The code comments, are that expected results or actual results?

Comment: Technically all work, that's actual output there, but if I return for example the first result it will show a cast error.